# Map Person Account as Individual in Relationship Map

Tags: financial-services-cloud

I'm trying to set the Person Account as Individual in Financial Service Cloud Scratch Org, so I can see the same Relationship Map.

When I'm using a sandbox, this is what is showing in Relationship Map

[image: Individual in Relationship Map in the sandbox]

When I'm using a scratch org, this is what is showing in Relationship Map

[image: Individual in Relationship Map in the scratch org]

Both scratch org and sandbox are mapping the record type to `PersonAccount` in the `Individual Record Type Mapper` Custom Metadata Type

[image: Individual Record Type Mapper]

This difference in Relationship Map shows different modals when adding and account or contact (clicking the button `+ Add Account` or `+ Add Contact` on the images above).

- The `+ Add Account` in an **Individual Record** (in my sandbox) shows a `Account Contact Relation` modal
- The `+ Add Contact` in an **Individual Record** (in my sandbox) shows a `Contact Contact Relation` modal
- The `+ Add Account` in a **Person Account Record** (in my scratch org) shows a `Account Account Relation` modal
- The `+ Add Contact` in a **Person Account Record** (in my scratch org) shows a `Account Contact Relation` modal

I need to develop in Scratch Org, but I need to see the same modals that appears in my sandbox. How can I set up the Person Account as an Individual?